# Splash Screen Label Animation iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a splash screen in swift. I put label to center of view controller. I want to this : when application starting,  label animating from bottom to center of page. This is what I want android version example  : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWkcCQ3EHxg . How can I do that ? Thank you

```
  UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {

        self.textLabel.center=self.view.center


    }, completion: nil)
```

I write this code but It is not solution.

---

Finally I wrote code. Maybe it will be useful for one

```
        label=UILabel()
        label.text="Splash Title"
        label?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(30, weight: UIFontWeightThin)
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.center=CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y: self.view.frame.height)
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

            self.label.center=CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y: self.view.frame.height/2)

            }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This is not a code writing request site, did u tried google yourself? this is very easy animation only, just put the Label on bottom, use `UIView.animateWithDuration` to set the Label frame back to center

Comment: **You can't animate splash screen** because u can't connect with UIViewController.

Answer (score 2):

You cant animate splash  screen directly because splash screen cannot be linked with view controller. What you can do is to create a splash screen and initial view controller which initial frame looks exactly like splash screen, and then you can animate view controller elements using uiview animations

Answer (score 0):

If you use `AutoLayout` you should create and `IBOutlet` to `NSLayoutConstraint` and change its value in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of view controller view cycle.

If your don't use `AutoLayout` - you should create outlet to your `UILabel` directly and change it's position or frame with animation.

P.s. there're 2 variants for you. Every action I think can be easily googled. It's hard to put all the details here, I think from this point you should at least try it doing yourself.